# Is Hyksos unique, or is there a rule about when κ + σ doesn't equal ξ?

Tags: ancient-greek, phonetics, loanwords, josephus, manetho

I was trying to find if there was a true analogue to the spelling of Hyksos in Greek without a ξ. Most instances of words with -κσ- in Classical and Hellenistic Greek were compounds with the prefix εκ-. Otherwise, it seems it's rare, but not impossible. You also see it in other foreign names like Ἀκσάφ.

Either way, these examples provide two rules for choosing -κσ- over ξ for a sigma following a kappa (foreign loanword or prefixed with εκ-), but perhaps there are more?

So, is the spelling of Hyksos as Ὑκσώς due to because it's a transcription of another language? Or is it because Josephus/Manetho conceives of it as a [word consisting of two elements](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0216%3Abook%3D1%3Awhiston+section%3D14) like εκ- compounds? And, ignoring archaic spellings or epichoric differences, are there other acceptable reasons why words might have -κσ- instead of -ξ- in Classical or Hellenistic Greek?

Comment: May not be irrelevant that the σ in Ἀκσάφ renders Hebrew שׁ /ʃ/, not שׂ or ס (both /s/); σ is the closest match but not necessarily a great one, so maybe it was a deliberate decision to leave it marked like that. I don't know about Ἀκσεΐρ, though—this thread is the only Google hit for it.

Comment: @Cairnarvon On closer inspection, Ἀκσεΐρ was found in an 18th century text written by Dapontes, so it's not the Greek in question after all.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the name is found in Eusebius as "Ὑκουσσώς", and it has been argued that Ὑκσώς in Manetho is just a textual corruption of that.

- The History of Nations, Volume 1: Ancient Empires of the East, [page 20](https://books.google.com/books?id=WrV9TKAeTtcC&pg=PA20)
- Wikipedia: ["Hyksos", §Etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyksos#Etymology)
- [https://incubator.wikimedia.org/wiki/Talk:Wp/cop/ϩⲉⲕϣⲱⲥⲓ](https://incubator.wikimedia.org/wiki/Talk:Wp/cop/%CF%A9%E2%B2%89%E2%B2%95%CF%A3%E2%B2%B1%E2%B2%A5%E2%B2%93)

It seems worth mentioning that Ὑξώς (seen in this [tweet](https://twitter.com/likethemagician/status/1475478043208687617)) is either a common mistake or possibly a third alternative textual variant of the name.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that on the Wiki, but I'm still unsure. Might it rather be the opposite, that the longer name Hellenized the odd one? Or corrected based on the Coptic? Does the Coptic pre-date the Greek? Even if it is corrupted, it still seems fishy. Separately, I checked TLG, and Ὑξώς doesn't appear there.

Comment: Hyksos is the name of some of the Pharao dynasties after their conquest int h17th century BC.  In the times of Herodotthe replacement of ks by  xi was not yet well established. By the total corruption of names of all the barbarians, of course, the copists didn't change a iota.  After Alexander the Hellenistc Egypt of the Ptolemaians, the county being bilingual, biliteral and  bireligous, writers had to be very careful in citing names

Comment: Returning to this, I should also note that the Coptic's transliteration is *hekšosi*, and despite the protests of that one user, I don't see how it's closer to Ὑκουσσώς than Ὑκσώς, with the exception of the double sigma. But there's no vowel between the ⲕ and ϣ in the Coptic word. Any further thoughts on this?

Comment: @cmw: Unfortunately, I don't think I know enough about this to say anything useful.